Issues with Point Addition to the Identity Element in Elliptic Curve Point Multiplication Over Weierstrass Curve in Projective Coordinates
I am currently implementing Elliptic Curve (EC) point multiplication over a Weierstrass curve using projective coordinates. Specifically, I am trying to add a point $P$ to the identity element (represented as $(0:1:0)$) according to the formulas provided in the answer to this question.
Based on my understanding, adding any point $P$ to the identity element should return the same point $P$. However, when I perform this operation, I end up with the result $(0:0:0)$, which seems incorrect.
Here’s a brief outline of what I’ve done:

I’ve implemented the formulas for point addition as described in the referenced answer.
The identity element is represented in projective coordinates as $(0:1:0)$.

Issue:
When I add a point $P$ to the identity element, instead of getting back $P$, I am getting $(0:0:0)$.
Questions:

Is my understanding correct that adding any point $P$ to the identity element $(0:1:0)$ should return $P$ in projective coordinates?
Could there be a mistake in my implementation of the point addition formula, or is there something I might be missing in handling projective coordinates?

Let's walk through an example to illustrate the problem of adding a point on the Weierstrass elliptic curve to the identity element in projective coordinates.
Given:

The Weierstrass equation: $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$
The identity element $O$ in projective coordinates: $O = (0 : 1 : 0)$

Let's choose a point $P = (x_1 : y_1 : z_1)$ on the elliptic curve.
For simplicity, let's assume:

$x_1 = 1$
$y_1 = 2$
$z_1 = 1$

So, $P = (1 : 2 : 1)$.
The identity element in projective coordinates:

$O = (0 : 1 : 0)$

Adding $P$ and $O$ in projective coordinates:
Given the formulas:

$u = y_2 z_1 - y_1 z_2$
$v = x_2 z_1 - x_1 z_2$
$w = u^2 z_1 z_2 - v^3 - 2 v^2 x_1 z_2$
$x_3 = v w$
$y_3 = u (v^2 x_1 z_2 - w) - v^3 y_1 z_2$
$z_3 = v^3 z_1 z_2$

Substituting $P = (1 : 2 : 1)$ and $O = (0 : 1 : 0)$:

$u = y_2 z_1 - y_1 z_2 = 1 \times 1 - 2 \times 0 = 1$
$v = x_2 z_1 - x_1 z_2 = 0 \times 1 - 1 \times 0 = 0$
$w = u^2 z_1 z_2 - v^3 - 2 v^2 x_1 z_2 = 1^2 \times 1 \times 0 - 0^3 - 2 \times 0^2 \times 1 \times 0 = 0$
$x_3 = v \times w = 0 \times 0 = 0$
$y_3 = u \times (v^2 \times x_1 \times z_2 - w) - v^3 \times y_1 \times z_2 = 1 \times (0^2 \times 1 \times 0 - 0) - 0^3 \times 2 \times 0 = 0$
$z_3 = v^3 \times z_1 \times z_2 = 0^3 \times 1 \times 0 = 0$

As shown, the point that I am getting is $(0:0:0)$ and not the same point $P = (1:2:1)$. Any insights or advice on what might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated!


Yes 2. yes check the formulas and their implementation..


@kelalaka , I did many time and do the calculations by my hand and it also gives Zeros.

What is $a,b,p$, and besides why $P$ is on the curve?

@kelalaka , I noticed this problem while I tried to implement Secp256k1 in projective coordinate using Python programing language utilizing Montgomery ladder method for implementing elliptical curve point multiplication, and as you the first step of the ladder method contains adding the generator point to the identity element.

If the curve is $y^2 = x^3 + 7$ then the point $P(1:2:1)$ is not on the curve! Actually $[(1 : 85895366384747149408010284714111852077055649506395260922968891100383188440129 : 1),
(1 : 29896722852569046015560700294576055776214335159245303116488692907525646231534 : 1)] )$ are the two points for which $x = 1$

@kelalaka
I used P=(1:2:1) just as an example, but the point that I used in the Python code is the generator point (base point) in the projective coordinate:
G = (55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240, 32670510020758816978083085130507043184471273380659243275938904335757337482424, 1) and when I added to the identity element I got zero result.

For testing the points must be valid no matter what you describe. I a little checked the formulas and they seems correct, post on [so] for code mistake?

I’m voting to close this question because the real question of the poster cannot be resolved without the code and that is a place for StackOverflow.
